# How to send a POST with JSON parameters using Apache HTTPClient 4.5. Getting 415 unsupported media type

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to send a POST request to my server (using Apache HTTPClient 4.5) with a set list of JSON parameters. I've followed some SO questions, but am running into problems.

When I use a javascript console to send the request, it works! Like this:

```
//Using JS console, I send a POST request and it works.
$.post('/createConfigData', {
    "tailSign": "A7ALE",
    "active": "Y"
});
//Get back 201
```

When I use **Apache HTTPClient 4.5** to try to do the same thing as above, I get back **415 unsupported media type**:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('/createConfigData');
String jsondata = "{\"tailSign\": \"A7ALE\",\"active\": \"Y\"}";

StringEntity jsonparam = new StringEntity(jsondata);
jsonparam.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
jsonparam.setChunked(true);

httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(jsonparam);

httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
```

**The data I have from the *working* request** is:

- **Request Headers:**

  - Host: "mysite.com"
  - User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
  - **Accept: `"*/*"`**
  - Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
  - Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
  - **Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"**
  - Referer: "mysite.com/index.html"
  - Content-Length: "288"
  - Cookie: "JSESSIONID=..."
  - Proxy-Authorization: "Basic ..."
  - Connection: "keep-alive"
  - Pragma: "no-cache"
  - Cache-Control: "no-cache"
- **Response Headers:**

  - Age: "0"
  - Connection: "Keep-Alive"
  - **Content-Type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"**
  - Date: "Wed, 19 Oct 2016 17:57:34 GMT"
  - Server: "Apache-Coyote/1.1"
  - Transfer-Encoding: "chunked"

I'm a bit confused on where to set the content type, whether it be the **entity** or the **httppost**

=======================

## More test cases

Setting **httpost's** content type to **json** gives me **`400`**

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('/createConfigData');
String jsondata = "{\"tailSign\": \"A7ALE\",\"active\": \"Y\"}";

StringEntity jsonparam = new StringEntity(jsondata);
jsonparam.setChunked(true);

httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(jsonparam);

httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
```

---

Setting **httpost's** content type to **x-www-form-urlencoded** gives me **`415`**

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('/createConfigData');
String jsondata = "{\"tailSign\": \"A7ALE\",\"active\": \"Y\"}";

StringEntity jsonparam = new StringEntity(jsondata);
jsonparam.setChunked(true);

httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(jsonparam);

httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
```

---

I also tried adding this line:

```
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
```

---

==================

## SOLUTION

Using **wireshark** I was able to figure out that there was an error message that goes along with the 400 bad request! It was just my JSON wasn't correct.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 21:33:25 GMT
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"code":400,"message":"Field ConfigName is Null, Invalid Value for Seat Count, Missing counts for DSU, ICMT, SVDU, TPMU, Login user details not found, Please enter valid lruData","fleetData":{"airlineData":null,"dimAircraftJson":null,"configData":null}}
```

Comment: I was trying to post XML via HttpClient and couldn't find a way so I switched to Spring's `RestTemplate`

Comment: Did you try to inspect the request headers which HttpClient sends? (you can use Wireshark for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting **415 unsupported media type** since your has overwritten **content-type** header to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8**. Just change it to:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('/createConfigData');
String jsondata = "{\"tailSign\": \"A7ALE\",\"active\": \"Y\"}";
StringEntity jsonparam = new StringEntity(jsondata);
jsonparam.setChunked(true);

httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(jsonparam);

httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
```

Comment: When I send it using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, I get `415`. When I send using the `json` content type, I get `400`. I think maybe somewhere it is not **accepting json** as the type. I tried adding `httppost.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");` but I still got `400`.